# Div height and overflow in nested layout to achieve scrollable child elements

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm having immense trouble understanding the concept of div height and overflow. Been searching for two days but I think I'm missing a key concept here...

My layout looks like this ([Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/W2T0zB27tW)):

[image]

The blue div does not scroll all the way to the end of the content. For some reason the div thinks that its height is larger than it really is (by exactly the height of the second navbar (red) on top of it). As a result, I can't scroll all the way to the bottom.

Also, having to repeat `h-full` for each child div until I reach the div that I want to be scrollable seems off to me but otherwise it assumes h-auto which is not good.

```
<div class="h-screen overflow-hidden">
  <div class="flex h-full flex-col overflow-hidden">
    <div class="w-full bg-slate-500 text-center text-white h-12 ">NAVBAR</div>
    <div class="flex h-full overflow-hidden">
      <div class="flex h-full basis-1/6">
        <div class="w-full bg-gray-300 text-center text-black">Sidebar</div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex h-full grow flex-col bg-slate-500">
        <div class="h-12 w-full shrink-0 bg-red-400 text-center">Second Navbar</div>
        <div class="h-full w-full grow bg-green-400">
          <div class="flex h-full">
            <div class="w-1/3 bg-blue-400 text-center">
              <div class="flex h-full flex-col overflow-y-scroll">
                <div>
                  Lorem....
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="h-full w-2/3 overflow-y-scroll bg-orange-400 text-center">Main content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look at the container(blue parent) under the second navbar. Its parent (the parent of the second navbar as well) have a height of about 831px. The navbar height is 3rem - which is about 48px.
But the blue parent has a height of 100% (of its parent) ~ 831px. So its basically overflowing (because 831+48 != 831).
If you put the `overflow:hidden` on the blue parent it'll hide the overflowing and blue container will scroll normally.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/SOO2rwiGsw